# Why my table won't align to center of the page with Bootsrap on my site but on codepen ok?

Tags: css, xcode, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 sets of identical code, my goal is to have a table align on the center of the page.

One works on Bootsnip and Codepen, but it doesn't work on my website...

I have tried to change my bootsrap template to CND, to no avail...

The page on my site is here:

http://xuzo.com/centeredleft

And the codepen is here:

http://codepen.io/Satearn/pen/JXwMLy

The code is identical for both...

The one on codepen centers in the middle, and the one on my site is aligned left.

I use this code to make it work:

```
.width
{width:600px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

</style>
<div class="table-responsive width">
<table class="table">
```

How can the same code give different results

Comment: you have bootstrap row and columns. Columns have floats so they start from the left.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `col-sm-4` to `col-sm-12`, See image.

[image]

**Alternative**: You should remove `row` and `col-sm-4` div, So your problem can also be solve by this.

Comment: What is the ==$0 about ?

Comment: $0 returns the most recently selected element or JavaScript object, $1 returns the second most recently selected one, and so on. its a new chrome feature

Comment: Thanks Imail, I was able to fix it using chrome dev tool, but the site is so complexe, I can't find the file where to change that...there is nothing in the HTML and isn't that from CDN ? Can't change it?

Comment: if you have problem to find html so yes you can solve your problem by css

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111124/discussion-between-ismail-farooq-and-bruno-vincent).

Answer (score 0):

Change col-sm-4 to col-sm-12,
or remove row and col-sm-4

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a Drupal Boostrap combination.

In order for this to work, the content item has to use display suite with a 12 column boostrap layout.